DPDK Flow director to multiple RX queues
Is there any way to use multiple RX queues in RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE DPDK Flow director?
uint16_t queue_indices[] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
struct rte_flow_action_queue queue = {.index = queue_indices};
struct rte_flow_action action2[]={
    [0]={.type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE,.conf = &queue,},
    [1]={.type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END}
};

If not, please suggest a way to direct packets that matches a particular pattern to multiple RX queues without the use of RSS.

From the OP it might follow that the desired behaviour is to duplicate/replay a matching packet and send each of the duplicates to a separate queue. If that's indeed the case, something like this would do:
struct rte_flow_action_queue q10 = { .index = 10 };
struct rte_flow_action_queue q11 = { .index = 11 };
/* ... */

struct rte_flow_action actions[] = {
    { .type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE, .conf = &q10 },
    { .type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE, .conf = &q11 },
    /* ... */
    { .type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END }
};

That said, not all NIC vendors support packet replay on vNIC level. The OP does not indicate which NIC they use (vendor ID, device ID) and does not mention DPDK version. With these two bits of information added to the OP, it should be possible to clarify whether the feature in question is supported or not.

Hi user23509140, Sorry if I didn't provide sufficient information. I need the matching packets to distribute evenly to specific RX queues and not the duplicates. I'm using intel x710 NIC and DPDK 20.11

You could achieve the 'multiqueues' effect with action port id or action vf. First direct different traffic flow patterns to different vf, each vf could have multiple queues. Receive packets from these vfs instead.
